# Testing Apache Camel servlet with spring cloud contract

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-cloud-contract

I have a spring boot application with routes defined as follows:

```
@Component
public class SampleRoute extends RouteBuilder {
 @Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

 rest("/customers-controller/")
.get("/customers").to("direct:getcustomer)
.get("/{id}").to("direct:customerDetail")
.get("/{id}/orders").to("direct:customerOrders")
.post("/neworder").to("direct:customerNewOrder");
}
```

I'm trying to create a contract to test this endpoint ('/customers') and create a stub that will be used in my consumer class.

A contract for messaging services like camel is similar to this:

```
    Contract.make {
    label("positive")
    input {
        messageFrom("seda:getcustomer")
        messageBody([
                id: "25_body"
        ])
        messageHeaders {
            messagingContentType(applicationJson())
//            header("id","123_header")
        }
    }
    outputMessage {
        sentTo("seda:iris-address-int")
        body([
                        "id":"25_body","firstname":null,"lastname":null,"email":null,"phone":null,"street":null,"city":null,"postcode":null
        ]
        )
        headers {
            messagingContentType()
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm not sure on how to define the contract such that it points to my chosen rest endpoint like I would do with a RestController.

Consider the test below. Is it possible to generate this test on the provider side using spring cloud contract given that I'm not using the `@RestController` but rather the `rest` component ?

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)


public class TestRestRoute {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
    @LocalServerPort
    int randomServerPort

 @Test
    public void test_bank_route() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        //call the REST API
       
        final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:"  + randomServerPort + "/customers-controller/customers";
        URI uri = new URI(baseUrl);
       
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, String.class );
        Assert.assertEquals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, Objects.requireNonNull(response.getHeaders().getContentType()).toString());
        Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCodeValue());
        Assert.assertNull(response.getBody());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this commit https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/commit/760d7105bde2f253ca0bff84fa3f4d5a35a1931e I've added a sample for Camel to spring cloud contract branch 3.0.x. Of course same rules apply to Spring Cloud Contract in other versions. In general what you can do is on the producer side:

Define a configuration for a route and extract the component URIs to separate methods:

```
@Configuration
class RouteConfiguration {

    @Bean
    RoutesBuilder myRouter() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                from(start())
                        .bean(MyProcessor.class)
                        .to(finish());
            }
        };
    }

    // rabbitmq://hostname[:port]/exchangeName?[options]
    String start() { return "rabbitmq:localhost/person?queue=person"; }

    String finish() {
        return "rabbitmq:localhost/verifications?queue=verifications";
    }

}
```

However in the contract we will leverage the `seda` component (the way you did it)

```
Contract.make {
    label("positive")
    input {
        messageFrom("seda:person")
        messageBody([
                age: 25
        ])
        messageHeaders {
            messagingContentType(applicationJson())
        }
    }
    outputMessage {
        sentTo("seda:verifications")
        body([
                eligible: true
        ])
        headers {
            messagingContentType(applicationJson())
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in the base class for the generated tests we will change the configuration to reflect what we have in the contract

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringRunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.boot.AutoConfigureMessageVerifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;

@RunWith(CamelSpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = BaseClass.TestConfiguration.class)
// IMPORTANT
@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
// IMPORTANT
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public abstract class BaseClass {

    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    static class TestConfiguration extends RouteConfiguration {

        // was:     rabbit
        // will be: a queue
        @Override
        String start() {
            return "seda:person";
        }

        @Override
        String finish() {
            return "seda:verifications";
        }
    }
}
```

We're overriding the `start()` and `finish()` methods. You could do sth similar in your case. Then on the consumer side you can reference it like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ConsumerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.assertj.core.api.BDDAssertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.AutoConfigureStubRunner;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerProperties;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(
        ids = "com.example:beer-api-producer-camel",
        stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL
)
// IMPORTANT
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate;
    @Autowired ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;
    @Autowired CamelContext camelContext;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // consumer -> seda:person
    //  producers -> seda:person -> person -> verifications -> seda:verifications
    // consumer -> seda:verifications

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        this.camelContext.getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(1);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_trigger_a_negative_verification() throws Exception {
        this.producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader("seda:person", new Person(17),
                "contentType", "application/json");

        String string =
                this.consumerTemplate.receiveBody("seda:verifications", String.class);
        Verification verification = this.objectMapper.readerFor(Verification.class).readValue(string);
        BDDAssertions.then(verification).isNotNull();
        BDDAssertions.then(verification.eligible).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    public void should_trigger_a_positive_verification() throws Exception {
        this.producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader("seda:person", new Person(25),
                "contentType", "application/json");

        String string =
                this.consumerTemplate.receiveBody("seda:verifications", String.class);
        Verification verification = this.objectMapper.readerFor(Verification.class).readValue(string);
        BDDAssertions.then(verification).isNotNull();
        BDDAssertions.then(verification.eligible).isTrue();
    }

}
```

Comment: It is a little unclear why I should leverage the seda component if i'm trying to do a test of the a camel rest component. I mean can I use 'GET', 'PUT' and 'POST' methods on that messaging component?

Comment: Because you're leveraging Camel to work with Rest endpoints and Spring Cloud Contract is not able to start an HTTP endpoint on the fly. What we can check though is that you're able to work with the given input and output messages in a given route of your choosing. We can only verify whether the input message is correct and whether you can parse the output message at this point. What you can do though is not use a messaging contract for this but an HTTP one. On the producer side use camel to build the route but test it with EXPLICIT mode and on the consumer side send a message to  WireMock

Comment: Understood. I tried using an HTTP contract for this but got an error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: You haven't configured a MockMVC instance`.  What do you mean by testing with EXPLICIT mode?

Comment: That means you can provide an url and port at which the request will be sent. You'd start your camel route, register it at a port X and then set the port X for rest assured after setting in the plugin the explicit mode. You can check the documentation for more info and the sample here https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer_webflux/pom.xml#L93

Comment: Can you write what you did exactly? Which road did you take?

Comment: The one using EXPLICIT mode `start your camel route, register it at a port X and then set the port X for rest assured after setting in the plugin the explicit mode`.